# Dúvida - Funcionamento de mapas em C++

Tags: c++, c++11, map

No intuito de comparar diferentes pares de calçados eu criei um mapa, o primeiro int representa tamanho e o char representa se é para o pé esquerdo ou direito ('e' ou 'd').

N representa o número de calçados diferentes.

No teste abaixo notei que se eu entrar dois calçados de mesmo tamanho o primeiro é mantido e o segundo não. Por qual razão isso ocorre?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(){

    int n, m,i=0;
    char l;
    std::map<int,char> calcado;

    std::cin>>n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin>>m;
        std::cin>>l;
        calcado.insert ( std::pair<int,char>(m,l) );
    }
    auto it = calcado.begin();
    auto en = calcado.begin();

    std::cout<<"Comecando!!!\n";

    for(auto it = calcado.cbegin(); it != calcado.cend(); ++it){
        std::cout << "NEW!\n";
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second<< "\n";
        std::cout << "Entrando no loop\n";
        for(auto en = calcado.cbegin(); en != calcado.cend(); ++en){
            std::cout << en->first << " " << en->second<< "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
3
40
d
40
e
45
d
```

Output:

```
Comecando!!!
NEW!
40 d
Entrando no loop
40 d
45 d
NEW!
45 d
Entrando no loop
40 d
45 d
```

Comment: Opa Leandro, o primeiro item de um map é a chave do mesmo, não é possível colocar 2 iguais, pois não vai ter como buscar posteriormente. Acredito que para seu algoritmo não é a melhor estrutura de dados.

Comment: Obrigado André!